# Proving this property of direct sums?

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

Let $V,W$ be subspaces of $R^n$. Prove that $R^n = V ⊕ W$, if and only if for every $\vec{x} \in R^n$ there exists a unique $\vec{v} \in V$, $\vec{w} \in W$ such that $\vec{v} + \vec{w} = \vec{x}$.

I'm totally stumped - I'm an intro linear algebra student, and this is the first time we've been introduced to direct sums. I get the general idea behind a direct sum - for example, I can easily understand how $R ⊕ R = R^2$, but I'm having trouble figuring out where to start this proof.

Any advice/tips/answers/proofs would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: the definition of direct sums we're given are:
Let $V$ be a vector space and let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces of $V$ . We write $V = U ⊕ W$ and call $V$ the direct sum of $U$ and $W$ if $V = U + W$ and $U ∩ W = \{\vec{0}\}$.

Comment: what is the definition of direct sum you're working with? (I ask because sometimes what you're trying to prove is taken as the definition itself, and there are several equivalent definitions)

Comment: The definition we're given is:
Let $V$ be a vector space and let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces of $V$ . We write $V = U ⊕ W$ and call $V$ the direct sum of $U$ and $W$ if $V = U + W$ and $U ∩ W = \{\vec{0}\}$.

Comment: ok my first suggestion is to write down very explicitly using universal and existential quantifiers what  $V = U+W$ means. From this, half the proof will be done (just compare side by side the two statements you're trying to prove once you have written everything down explicitly). After doing so, if you're still stuck after a while, post your attempt, then we can guide you better

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to formalize it, but I do understand what you're getting at. What I got is:

$V = U + W$ means that $V = \{\vec{u} + \vec{w}: \vec{v} \in U, \vec{w} \in W\}$

which means that, by definition, for every $\vec{x} \in R^n$ there exists *a* $\vec{v} \in V$, $\vec{w} \in W$ such that $\vec{v} + \vec{w} = \vec{x}$. What I'm having trouble with is showing that a) that the addition of vectors $\vec{v} + \vec{w} = \vec{x}$ is a *unique* combination, and that b) the converse is true to prove the biconditional.

Comment: Ok, so for $\implies$, you need to somehow invoke the fact that $V \cap W = \{0\}$ to prove the uniqueness. For the converse, it's a very similar argument, just run it backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $R^n = V \oplus W$. By definition, we can write any $x\in R^n$ as $x= v+w$ with $v\in V, w \in W$. We show that this is unique:

Indeed, assume we have another decomposition

$$x= v+w= v'+w'$$

Then $v-v' = w'-w \in V \cap W = \{0\}$

and thus $v= v', w=w'$ showing uniqueness of the decomposition.

Conversely, assume that we can write any $x \in R^n$ as $x= v+w$ in a unique way. Trivially then $R^n = V+W$. Also, let $x \in V \cap W$. Then

$$x= x + 0 = 0 + x$$ are two decompositions and by uniqueness we must have $x=0$, showing $V \cap W = \{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you!!! This worked great!